# Rename nuget package content file as per target project

Tags: nuget, nuget-package, nuget-spec

While installing my custom Nuget package to target cs projects, I need to rename few content files as per the target project name. E.g. If the target project name is "XYZ.Model" then my Nuget package content file should be installed as "XYZ.Model.EF.tt".

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handled this via POSH script which is part of my nuget package.